# API hit using CURL

Tags: php, curl

Am trying to access an API using CURL
I can access the API from my browser.
But cannot get the data from the same api(using the same API key)
using curl.

I am getting this error.
403 Developer Over Qps

Please let me know what can be the reason for this.

Earlier it was working. I am facing this issue for the past 2 days.!!

please check the code below:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://api.perfb.com/api/api.php?requestmethod=json&responsemethod=xml');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 900);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $vJson);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($info);exit;
```

Comment: please show relevant code, url, error message explanation, and anything that could help us to help you.

Comment: 403 Developer Over Qps means you are issuing a number of Queries per Second above the maximum. You must throtle your queries. Try introducing a delay between queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error usually signifies that you're hitting the server too often (i.e. developer over allowed queries per second). Slow down your code, put some delays in. In browser, you're doing it manually, so it's likely quite a bit slower than your code.

Comment: Am not using any queries as of now, just trying to print the response which I get from the API , which eventually results in "403 deevloper over rate " error.
Thanks

Comment: my code now looks like this which is now working:
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 900);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($info);

Comment: I couldn't find any information on what api.perfb.com is, and we told you what the most probable issue was. If you can't solve it from that, I suggest you ask the service provider (api.perfb.com staff), as they are the only ones who can give you the accurate information as to what is causing the error. However, "Am not using any queries" is wrong: your `curl_exec($ch)` is performing a query.

Answer (score 3):

Qps means Queries Per Second

Are you hitting the server repeatedly with curl in a loop for example? Try adding a pause after each call and see if that works.

Comment: no am just getting the response of the api call..which is failing...:-(

Comment: Is the API publicly available? Maybe your browser authenticates as an anonymous user which has unlimited access and your script's user has a limit imposed by the API author? Or vice versa?

Comment: I just commented this part
  //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $vJson);
and used curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
where 
$url = "http://api.perfb.com/api/api.php?api_key=".$key."&action=buyat.affiliate.content.ticketmaster.event.venueevent&".$marketKey."&perpage=100&page=".$page;';

and now it works...
but am not sure what really was the issue when i used CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS !!